# Issues with BufferedReader reading output from CMD processbuilder (JAVA)?

Tags: java, cmd, process, bufferedreader, processbuilder

I am running into some problems using ProcessBuilder, Process, and BufferedReaders in my Java program. For some inputs, the function runs perfectly but with others the BufferedReader reads nothing and returns empty strings. I am not sure what may be causing this bug.

I have tried debugging and for those situations where nothing is being read, the BufferedReader is completely skipping the loop. For example, when I pass in the command as 'ipconfig', which has >50 lines of CMD output, it returns every line exactly as displayed. But when I pass in the command as 'java -version', it completely skips the output (there are 3 lines that should be read).

ProcessBuilder/Reading function:

```
public static String runCommandToStdOut(String command) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        pBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        String[] processArray = command.split(" ");
        pBuilder.command(processArray);
        process = pBuilder.start();
        process.waitFor();
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        //reading cmd output to string
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sBuilder.append(line);
            sBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        return sBuilder.toString();
    }
```

How I am calling the function:

```
try {
            String stdOut = osCommandService.runCommandToStdOut("java -version");
}
```

The stdOut string in the second code section is empty. That means the line 'sBuilder.toString' is an empty string after the function is run. The output that I see when I run 'java -version' directly in my cmd prompt is 3 lines long, which evidently isn't being read properly.

Comment: `process.waitFor()` waits for the process to finish.  Once it has finished, it is unlikely that there will be anything to read.  Call `process.waitFor()` *after* you have read the output.

Comment: Moving the ```process.waitFor()``` line to after the while loop made no difference. Also tried it after initializing the BufferedReader. I have a feeling this has to do with some permission in running the command. Maybe the command 'java -version' isn't a built in windows command, but commands like 'ipconfig' are. Do I need to do something with the PATH variable?

Comment: I believe `java -version` prints information to standard error, not standard output.  Try calling [pBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream%28boolean%29) before starting the process.

Comment: I will try that and let you know as soon as I can. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Redirecting the error stream fixed the issue. Thank you!